# room + внешняя sqlite

Tags: android, android-room

Я подключила библиотеку room. Создала по туториалу необходимые интерфейсы и классы:

```
 @Entity
public class ModelPoem {
    public String title;
    public String poem;
    public String subject;
    public String years;
    @PrimaryKey
    public int key;

    public ModelPoem(){}




    public ModelPoem(String poem, int key,  String title, String subject, String years) {
       this.title = title;
        this.poem = poem;
        this.key = key;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.years = years;
    }

    @Dao
public interface PoemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ModelPoem")
    List<ModelPoem> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ModelPoem WHERE `key` = :id")
    ModelPoem getById(int id);

    @Insert
    void insert(ModelPoem modelPoem);

    @Update
    void update(ModelPoem modelPoem);

    @Delete
    void delete(ModelPoem modelPoem);

}



@Database(entities = {ModelPoem.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DatabaseHelper extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract PoemDao getPoemDao();
}



 public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;
    private DatabaseHelper db;

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.class, "database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    public DatabaseHelper getDatabaseInstance() {
        return db;
    }
}
```

Как теперь мне это все связать с БД, которая уже заполнена и лежит в assets? В документации такой информации не нашла.

Comment: вам нужно смотреть по миграции между room и sqlite, например [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343691/how-to-migrate-android-sqlite-database-from-internal-storage-to-room). сам я такого не делал, поэтому полноценный ответ написать не могу

Comment: Больше [информации по теме](https://www.google.com/m/search?q=migrate%20from%20sqlite%20to%20room)